# "OnThisDay" feature with Nextjs using getServerSideProps with Date.now() at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to implement a "OnThisDay" Wikipedia style feature with Nextjs, showing an event that happened on that day. For this I have a function that looks like this:

```
const list = [{"dateOfDeath": "2000-01-01", "name": "X"},{"dateOfDeath": "2000-01-02", "name": "Y"]

const dateObj = new Date();
const currentDay =
  ('0' + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  ('0' + dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2);

export default function GetToday() {
  return list.filter(
    (person) => person.dateOfDeath.slice(5) === currentDay
  );
}
```

I'm then getting this via getStaticProps:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const today = GetToday();
  return {
    props: {
      today
    },
    revalidate: 10
  };
};
```

This all works fine and well, however it seems that the Date object is created once at build time, so the page is stuck with whatever date the site was build on.
I purposfully set revalidate to 10s trying to solve this, which didn't work. I also tried using `getServerSideProps` instead but that didn't change anything either. I'm deploying the site with Docker, using pretty much the Docker template of the Nextjs repo.

Does someone know a way, that a new Date object is created at runtime?

Comment: Try calling `new Date()` and the `currentDay` logic inside the `GetToday` function.

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs will compile pages before serving them to client so it won't show that date at runtime, and using invalidate to fix that is a very very bad solution because it kills the purpose of doing caching for performance at all.

Use something like `useEffect` from react, so that you can execute code client side.  Anything inside `useEffect` will only get executed `onComponentMount` so it will only execute once the dom is rendered and loaded in client's browser, it won't ever execute server side.  Put that date code inside a useeffect so it only executes once it hits the browser.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // anything here will only execute on client side once dom is rendered
  // get the date here and set it here using whatever javascript you want
}, [])
```

You could also use `getServerSideProps` and it should work but it's a bad solution to this, you should not be calling your server, refresh your page and invalidate the cache, every time you want to get today's date, that would be terrible...

Another thing is that I would not use dates like this, it's hard to maintain, hard to read, hard for the next dev to figure out what on earth that date is doing and really difficult to debug, and very easy to make mistakes with edge cases like 29th February.  In your case for example you have a bug that you would only have figured out next year, if someone died last *year* on the exact same month and day, it will include them in that array, since it will match `person.dateOfDeath.slice(5) === currentDay`.  If you don't want to constantly think of every possible edge case with very tricky date mangement, rather use a library like `luxon`.  Then instead you could have done something like `DateTime.fromISOString(user.dateOfDeath).hasSame('day', DateTime.utc()`, your code will also just be a lot easier to read and maintain for future developers.  Also don't save dates in a format like that, store it as an ISO string with `new Date().toISOString()`, in UTC time.  Date can be formatted in hundreds of ways dependeing on language/region/locale settings, better you stick to the best standard for working with dates.